# Active Record Query - default value for find if nil value supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am searching for a user in one of my controller actions.  Sometimes, params[:user_id] will be nil, and in that case, the search should yield the current_user.  The following two search methods seem to produce the same result

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]||=current_user)
```

and

```
@user = User.where('id = ?', params[:user_id]).first || current_user
```

The questions are:

1) Which search method is more appropriate, and 
2) Is there a way to bypass the search all together if params[:user_id] is nil?

I'm sure I could come up with a if/else statement to accomplish line 2 but that feels hackish to me.  But, maybe it's not?

Thanks!

Comment: First option throw an exception if params[:user_id] is invalid. If you want that when it is invalid @user = current_user, use the second.

Comment: @drinor - ???  I am currently using the first solution and the correct result is populated in the user variable (i.e., no exception is thrown) when params[:user_id] is nil.

Comment: yes, when params[:user_id] is nil all is ok, but if you send other value for example: params[:user_id] = "not_valid" (some id that don't exists) find throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It's not going to be an issue in this case but thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect place for the ternary operator

```
@user = params[:user_id] ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
```

I'd like to add a little more.

```
I'm sure I could come up with a if/else statement to accomplish line 2 but that
feels hackish to me. But, maybe it's not?
```

A lot of developers love to get *cute* with slick one-liners instead of the more readable `if/else` control flow. **I do it too!**

While you write code, try to remember that readability is far more important than a slick one-liner. Having said that, your specific example is a great place to use the ternary operator but the alternative `if/else` is just as acceptable. Ruby even lets you make it slightly *cooler* than some other languages.

```
@user = if params[:user_id]
  User.find(params[:user_id])
else
  current_user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you are going with this, but the first one to me is more Rails-ish.

You don't need the `=`

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]||current_user)
```

Comment: It's not a mistake. You can also pass objects to `find`. It doesn't have to be an integer, hence `.id` is not necessary.